# Nginx times out on proxy_pass without any logging

Tags: nginx, proxy

I use NGINX for reverse proxy/load balancing to my Ruby On Rails application, on a server with other php applications using fastcgi, they don't have any issue though.
I have issues with NGINX just stop serving connections, it doesn't show up in any access logs or error logs.

I noticed the problem when i clicked around on my application and got a timed out error, which doesn't come up in the logs at all, in nginx nor unicorn.

I tested to change from socket to port and to benchmark that port, which worked, but if I changed that to nginx it will fail most of them or even all of them.

My nginx config looks like this:

```
upstream unicorn_app_production {
    #server unix:/tmp/unicorn.app_production.sock;
    server localhost:8080;
}



server {

  listen 80;


  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 600s;

  error_page 500 502 504 /500.html;
  error_page 503 @503;

  server_name dev.app.com;
  server_name_in_redirect off;
  port_in_redirect        off;

  root /var/www/rails.app.com/current/public;
  #try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn_app_production;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://unicorn_app_production;
    #proxy_read_timeout 180s;
    proxy_connect_timeout       300;
    proxy_send_timeout          300;
    proxy_read_timeout          300;
    send_timeout                300;
    proxy_next_upstream error;
    # limit_req zone=one;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/app_production.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/app_production.error.log;
  }
...
}
```

And i use siege for testing if nginx can handle my connections:
`siege -c 5 -r 5 http://dev.app.com:8080` is directly to unicorn and without 8080 is to nginx. directly to unicorn works without any issue but to nginx it will look like this:

```
/# siege -c 5 -r 5 http://dev.app.com
** SIEGE 2.70
** Preparing 5 concurrent users for battle.
The server is now under siege...socket: connection timed out
socket: connection timed out
socket: connection timed out
socket: connection timed out
socket: connection timed out
^C
Lifting the server siege...      done.                                                                                                                                                         
Transactions:                  10 hits
Availability:                  66.67 %
Elapsed time:                  39.52 secs
Data transferred:               0.03 MB
Response time:                  0.10 secs
Transaction rate:               0.25 trans/sec
Throughput:                     0.00 MB/sec
Concurrency:                    0.03
Successful transactions:          10
Failed transactions:               5
Longest transaction:            0.13
Shortest transaction:           0.05
```

What is the problem and what am I doing wrong?

PS. proof that my unicorn works totally fine:

```
/# siege -c 20 -r 6 http://dev.app.com:8080
** SIEGE 2.70
** Preparing 20 concurrent users for battle.
The server is now under siege..      done.                                                                                                                                                     Transactions:                     120 hits
Availability:                 100.00 %
Elapsed time:                   4.63 secs
Data transferred:               1.32 MB
Response time:                  0.12 secs
Transaction rate:              25.92 trans/sec
Throughput:                     0.29 MB/sec
Concurrency:                    2.99
Successful transactions:         120
Failed transactions:               0
Longest transaction:            0.28
Shortest transaction:           0.05
```

Comment: Increase nginx error log level to INFO or DEBUG: Does that help?

Comment: Tried that out and it did not work. it didn't come up. I wonder if it is something outside nginx that is blocking it now. I am not sure.